# Gnuplot Windows disappears immediately in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot for a C++ project in **Ubuntu** and decided to use the gnuplot-iostream interface. I am using the sample code in [here](https://gitorious.org/gnuplot-iostream/pages/BasicUsage). Gnuplot windows popsup and disappears quickly. I also used `Gnuplot gp(“gnuplot -persist”);` but nothing changed!

Is it a bug or I should set some other parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your program ends execution and quits. This is very similar to what happens if you call gnuplot without any interface from the command line, e.g. try:

```
echo "plot x" | gnuplot
```

You will see the graph pops out and then quits. What you can do to prevent this is to add a pause:

```
echo "plot x ; pause 10" | gnuplot
```

The code above will keep the graph window open for 10 seconds. I think you might need a similar solution.